# Gsutil perfdiag equivalent in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gsutil, aws-s3-client

We need to evaluate the latency/bandwidth while we try to upload/download an object from an EC2 instance to an S3 bucket.

We did the same in GCP using the `gsutil perfdiag` command. However, I cannot find any official command in AWS.

**Is there any tool we can use to extract that information?**

Info we are looking for:

1. Latency for upload/download/delete object(s).
2. Bandwidth to upload/download/delete object(s).